# Putting a UIScrollView inside a UIPageView, scrolling doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm making a pageview that has a bunch of scrollable pages inside it. I have the pageview working, and the viewcontrollers that it rotates each have a scroll view inside them. The problem is, I think, that the scrolling doesn't happen because the touches don't get through to the pageview. The scroll view should only scroll vertically, while the pageview works with the horizontal scrolling. Is it possible to send through only the vertical touches, or is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a storyboard, open the Attributes inspector of the embedded `UIScrollView` and deselect the "Shows Horizontal Indicator" option. Do the same on the `UIPageViewController`, but for the "Shows Vertical Indicator". However, you also have to ensure that the scroll view's contents aren't wider than the scroll view itself; to do this, just constrain the contents' width to be equal to the scroll view's *parent*.

Comment: I did the ScrollView one, but there isn't anything like that on the UIPageView, and I can't find the attribute in code either. With the ScrollView's horizontal indicator disabled, it still doesn't work. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You're right--`UIPageViewController`s use a `UIScrollView` internally, but you can't get at it programmatically or in IB. I haven't tried this, but you may try iterating over the page view controller's `UIGestureRecognizers` array and setting each one's `delaysContentTouches` property to `true`. This tells the page view controller's swipe/pan gestures to let the subviews' gestures (if any) to handle gestures first, and continue only if the subviews' gestures fail.

Comment: Hm UIGestureRecognizers have the delaysTouchesBegan / Ended, I set them to true and false both, but neither did anything as far as I can tell.